# HybridAuth not working - User profile request failed(Google)

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0, hybridauth

I'm using SocialLogin plugin for WordPress which relies on HybridAuth for authentication. However, when I try to login with Google, I get `"User profile request failed. Most likely the user is not connected to the provider and he should to authenticate again."` error. I've tried Googling the solution, unsuccessfully.

Also, when I try to login with StackOverflow or Yahoo! I get `Unspecified error!`

Answer (score 4):

I came across this issue also ...

Your question is more than an year old but here you go the solution:

Go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and activate Google+ API access.

That worked out for me!

Answer (score -3):

It generally occurs to me in two conditions.

1. Session lost when you use for example back button or directly visiting the page instead of visiting via link.
2. Some times you need to clear your cache, logout and login to site but clean logout
       generally fix.

I also want you to know that Hybrid Auth is a dead project.

Comment: Please post a reference to Hybrid Auth being dead.